# Adding params dynamically to form fields Rails and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to created a dynamic form in rails with a little bit of javascript I have a problem I only get one row in the output when using `pry` apparently it's because I have the same params for every field input since I use jQuery .clone, maybe someone has struggled with something similar can share some knowledge, how to dynamically add index to params in this form with javascript ? Thanks.  [image: dynamic form]

jQuery to clone the element

```
$(document).on("click", ".button-remove", function(e) {
  $(this).closest(".duplicate").remove();
    e.preventDefault();                    
});

$(".btn-add").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let cloned = $(".duplicate:last").clone();
    cloned.insertBefore(this);
    cloned.find(":text").val("");
});
```

HTML to clone

```
<div class="duplicate">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" 
         name="contribution[item_name]">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">      
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="item_quantity">Number of items</label>
        <input min="1" class="form-control" 
        type="number" value="1"
        name="contribution[item_quantity]">
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="contribution[item_type]">Category</label>
           <select class="form-control" 
           name="contribution[item_type]">
             <option value="1">Entrée</option>
             <option value="2">Plat</option>
             <option value="3">Dessert</option>
             <option value="4">Softs</option>
             <option value="5">Alcool</option>
             <option value="6">Autres</option>
           </select>
       </div>
         <a href="#" class="button-remove">
           Remove item
         </a> 
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<button class="btn-add">
  Add new row
</button>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this one by changed the name input of each field, I simply added an index, I'm sure there is a cleaner solution but until something better this works !

```
function addParams(){
   let items = $('.duplicate').length;
   items -= 1;
  $('.duplicate:last input.item_name').attr('name', function() {
      return `contribution[item_name_${items}]`;
  });

  $('.duplicate:last input.item_quantity').attr('name', function() {
      return `contribution[item_quantity_${items}]`;
  });

  $('.duplicate:last select.item_type').attr('name', function() {
      return `contribution[item_type_${items}]`;
  }); 
}
```

binding.pry

```
"contribution"=>{
"item_name"=>"un", 
"item_quantity"=>"1", 
"item_type"=>"1",
"item_name_1"=>"deux",
"item_quantity_1"=>"1", 
"item_type_1"=>"2",
"item_name_2"=>"trois",
"item_quantity_2"=>"1", 
"item_type_2"=>"3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a hidden field?  Somewhere in your html i.e.

```
<input id="form_group_id" name="form_group_id" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

so something like:

```
    <div class="duplicate">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" 
             name="contribution[item_name]">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">      
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="item_quantity">Number of items</label>
            <input min="1" class="form-control" 
            type="number" value="1"
            name="contribution[item_quantity]">
            <input id="form_group_id" name="form_group_id" type="hidden" value="1" />
          </div>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="form-group">
             <label for="contribution[item_type]">Category</label>
               <select class="form-control" 
               name="contribution[item_type]">
                 <option value="1">Entrée</option>
                 <option value="2">Plat</option>
                 <option value="3">Dessert</option>
                 <option value="4">Softs</option>
                 <option value="5">Alcool</option>
                 <option value="6">Autres</option>
               </select>
           </div>
             <a href="#" class="button-remove">
               Remove item
             </a> 
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

You'll need to update your JS to increment the value of your hidden field but that should be easy.

Comment: Thanks @lacostenycoder I'm looking into it, I'm really new at javascript might take me the night to get this working thanks for your input

Comment: Not really working out for me I still only get the last row but it's a lead thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think what you try to do is done in this Railscasts episode about dynamic forms:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms

For nested dynamic forms (that I think it is not your case but just in case), you can use [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).